# Syntactic , semantic and change the meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context, syntactic-analysis, semantics

> He set the apples down and took her by (the arm) or (by arm).

If I used (by arm), are syntactic semantics acceptable? Does the meaning change?

Comment: Is your question about whether to use "by the arm" or "by arm", or is it about syntax and semantics?

Comment: Are you focused only on that one specific sentence, or are you asking in general? Different contexts will give the same phrase (or construction) different meanings. Please clarify the scope of your question. For instance, *by arm* would be fine if the sentence continued on in a certain way—and it would also mean the same thing as *by the arm*. Do you only care about *arm* or would *by car* or *by the car* also be considered in your question?

Answer (score -1):

You have to say "by the arm". "By arm" is not correct. It is not a matter of semantics or syntax, but of idiomaticity ([ref.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/262842806_A_Model_of_Idiomaticity/link/55ca5dfb08aeca747d69e797/download)).

> As an introduction, I will offer the following two definitions of
>   idiomaticity:
>   (i) nativelike selection of expression (inspired by Pawley and Syder (1983))
>   (ii) that which one has to know over and above rules and words (inspired
>   by Fillmore et al (1988))

…

> Allerton (1989: 36), realizing that there are syntactically and lexically unmotivated
>   "locutional co-occurrence restrictions", which a language-user needs to master, suggests
>   that these justify the introduction of "idiomatics" as a special branch of lexicology.